# What does the graph of this equation depict?

Tags: calculus

I would really like to know a step by step explanation of the graph of this equation.Thank you so much for your answer.
$$4x^2+y^2-8x+2y=11$$

Comment: Seeing that several of your questions have been put on hold, it might be useful for you to have a look at the FAQ post: [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) After all, having too many closed questions might lead to a [question ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info) - which means you would not be able to ask new questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2x-2)^2+(y+1)^2=11+4+1$$

$$\dfrac{(x-1)^2}4+\dfrac{(y+1)^2}{16}=1$$

which is an ellipse.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Identifying_rotated_conic_sections).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and clear response!!

Comment: yes, you are righ @labbhattacharjee:

Comment: its a small mistake, the right answer is:

Comment: $$\dfrac{(x-1)^2}4+\dfrac{(y+1)^2}{16}=1$$

Comment: @Billy110, Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint see if we have a second degree equation $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c =0
$ then if $h^2-ab <0$ then its ellipse if its greater than $0$ then hyperbola and if equal to $0$ then parabola.thus  consider cases of $h^2- ab $ from that you get $h^2-ab\leq 0$ thus it represents an ellipse .

Comment: could you  please tell what $h$ and $a$ as well as $b$ represent? and the formula $h^2- ab$. I think it is a really interesting formula

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! it is $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$